# searching through array-lists , having a hard time

Tags: java

I have a method here, its job is to take in 3 array lists, and return a value.

THE 3 ARRRAY LIST specific jobs

1. names entereed by user
2. this is a arraylist with all names I made, these are player names
3. for each name , i have given a specific value. I am using this to cross reference my position with that value I assigned that name

I know the third might be confusing to understand, so ill try breaking it down a bit. so say someone enters a name, i look up that name in my playernames, and once i find that position, I can the position to access that players ranking from playerNumber. Because I put the names in one list, and numbers in another. The positions match for names and numbers in both lists

My problem is that I keep getting 0, as my returned result. Im not sure why, please advise :<

**unrealated: **Guys the reason why im using arraylists is because this is as far as I have learned in java. I will be learning new topics as time comes, im just trying my best to use the skills I have to make a fun project. So sorry if its really nooby, this is the best I can do right now

```
public static int meth(List names, List searchingLis, List nameNumber){
      int totalGive=0;

      int totalRecieve=0;

      int sizer=names.size()-1;

       int ret=-1000;

       int makeSureAllPlayerAdded=sizer;

       int returningValue=0;
       do{

      for(int i=0;i<names.size();i++){


      int currenSearchRanking=(int) nameNumber.get(i);



      if(names.get(i).equals(searchingLis.get(i))){



      int valueToLookUpInNames=i;
      int AddingValue=(int) nameNumber.get(valueToLookUpInNames);
      returningValue=returningValue+AddingValue;

      System.out.println(returningValue+"ret vales");



makeSureAllPlayerAdded--;
      }

      }

      return returningValue;
       }while(makeSureAllPlayerAdded<=0);
    }
```

Comment: You don't even have a return statement. Please provide a [mcve] and ask a clear question.

Comment: hey sorry about that, my copy and paste didnt go through with that part. I fixed it! Please forgive me

Comment: any reason why you don't want to combine searchList and nameNumber into a HashMap? it'll make your look up easier.

Comment: I would do that, but im a beginner. I havent learned about those yet, im just trying to make a project with the stuff I have learned so far. Hashmaps are one of the next topics I will be covering.

Comment: Poor title. Please edit to describe your specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you're saying that `searchingLis` and `nameNumber` have matching positions which effectively represent a row, and that `names` is just an arbitrary list of unmatched names provided by the user.

Your most fatal flaw, then, is in the line `if(names.get(i).equals(searchingLis.get(i))){`.

In it, you'll only see a match from `names` in your `searchingLis` if it is in the same position.  So, if `searchingList` held ["John","Mary"] and `names` held ["Mary"], then there would be no match because you only look at the `searchingList` member in position 0, rather than comparing each member of `searchingList` to each name.

Comment: :o I had no idea, thanks mate. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: It's just for practice, right?  I'd suggest scrapping this project and taking smaller bites.  Find three ways to iterate through a List, print all members containing the letter "a", print an unsorted array, sort it, then print the sorted version, etc.  Keep your learning tasks simple, and defer some of your creativity until you can confidently create a POJO, a Set, a List, and a Map.